# Can't close browser in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need close InAppBrowser when some page starts load, my code:

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}

const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
  zoom: 'no',
  hardwareback: 'no',
  location: 'no'
};

const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/', '_self', options);
browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => {
  if (event.url === 'https://ionicframework.com/getting-started') {
    console.log('close!');
    browser.close();
  }
});
```

When */getting-started* page starts load i see in Console 'close!', but browser won't close

Comment: You could add 'location=yes' as an attribute. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-close-inapp-browser-pragmatically/120088 please check this doc and @Shequeri answer

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj This is not what I need. I need automatic closing browser, when some url starts load